# Write a sequence without having 0 at any place

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            //this will be real amount rows i need to generate member id for 
            //var quantity =13000;

            // for testing we can use 20 
            var quantity =20;
            var perpackcards = 99;

            //this is how much total member ids should be
            var totalrows = quantity * perpackcards;

            var memberIdprefix = 'M';
            var alphaStart = '';
            var memberIdStart = 2111111;

            //  i have to achieve sevral other goals, so that i need to run loop this way, loop inside loop.    
            for (i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                for(j = 0; j < perpackcards; j++) {
                    var result = parseInt(memberIdStart) + j;    
                    //console.log(memberIdStart+'--'+j);
                    console.log(result);
                }
                memberIdStart += 100;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to generate a sequence using member id, so this code outputs the member is like this:

Output I am getting:

```
    2111111
    2111112
    2111113
    2111114
    2111115
    2111116
    2111117
    2111118
    2111119
    2111120
    2111121
    2111122
    2111123
    2111124
    2111125
    2111126
    2111127
    2111128
    2111129
    2111130
    2111131
    2111132
    2111133
    2111134
    2111135
    2111136
    2111137
    2111138
    2111139
    2111140
    2111141
    2111142
    2111143
    2111144
    2111145
    2111146
    2111147
    2111148
    2111149
    2111150
    2111151
    2111152
    2111153
    2111154
    2111155
    2111156
    2111157
    2111158
    2111159
    2111160
    2111161
    2111162
    2111163
    2111164
    2111165
    2111166
    2111167
    2111168
    2111169
    2111170
    2111171
    2111172
    2111173
    2111174
    2111175
    2111176
    2111177
    2111178
    2111179
    2111180
    2111181
    2111182
    2111183
    2111184
    2111185
    2111186
    2111187
    2111188
    2111189
    2111190
    2111191
    2111192
    2111193
    2111194
    2111195
    2111196
    2111197
    2111198
    2111199
    2111200
    2111201
    2111202
    2111203
    2111204
    2111205
    2111206
    2111207
    2111208
    2111209
    2111211
    2111212
    2111213
    2111214
    2111215
    2111216
    2111217
    2111218
    2111219
    2111220
    2111221
    2111222
    2111223
    2111224
    2111225
    2111226
    2111227
    2111228
    2111229
    2111230
    2111231
    2111232
    2111233
    2111234
    2111235
    2111236
    2111237
    2111238
    2111239
    2111240
    2111241
    2111242
    2111243
    2111244
    2111245
    2111246
    2111247
    2111248
    2111249
    2111250
    2111251
    2111252
    2111253
    2111254
    2111255
    2111256
    2111257
    2111258
    2111259
    2111260
    2111261
    2111262
    2111263
    2111264
    2111265
    2111266
    2111267
    2111268
    2111269
    2111270
    2111271
    2111272
    2111273
    2111274
    2111275
    2111276
    2111277
    2111278
    2111279
    2111280
    2111281
    2111282
    2111283
    2111284
    2111285
    2111286
    2111287
    2111288
    2111289
    2111290
    2111291
    2111292
    2111293
    2111294
    2111295
    2111296
    2111297
    2111298
    2111299
    2111300
    2111301
    2111302
    2111303
    2111304
    2111305
    2111306
    2111307
    2111308
    2111309
    2111311
    2111312
    2111313
    2111314
    2111315
    2111316
    2111317
    2111318
    2111319
    2111320
    2111321
    2111322
    2111323
    2111324
    2111325
    2111326
    2111327
    2111328
    2111329
    2111330
    2111331
    2111332
    2111333
    2111334
    2111335
    2111336
    2111337
    2111338
    2111339
    2111340
    2111341
    2111342
    2111343
    2111344
    2111345
    2111346
    2111347
    2111348
    2111349
    2111350
    2111351
    2111352
    2111353
    2111354
    2111355
    2111356
    2111357
    2111358
    2111359
    2111360
    2111361
    2111362
    2111363
    2111364
    2111365
    2111366
    2111367
    2111368
    2111369
    2111370
    2111371
    2111372
    2111373
    2111374
    2111375
    2111376
    2111377
    2111378
    2111379
    2111380
    2111381
    2111382
    2111383
    2111384
    2111385
    2111386
    2111387
    2111388
    2111389
    2111390
    2111391
    2111392
    2111393
    2111394
    2111395
    2111396
    2111397
    2111398
    2111399
    2111400
    2111401
    2111402
    2111403
    2111404
    2111405
    2111406
    2111407
    2111408
    2111409
    2111411
    2111412
    2111413
    2111414
    2111415
    2111416
    2111417
    2111418
    2111419
    2111420
    2111421
    2111422
    2111423
    2111424
    2111425
    2111426
    2111427
    2111428
    2111429
    2111430
    2111431
    2111432
    2111433
    2111434
    2111435
    2111436
    2111437
    2111438
    2111439
    2111440
    2111441
    2111442
    2111443
    2111444
    2111445
    2111446
    2111447
    2111448
    2111449
    2111450
    2111451
    2111452
    2111453
    2111454
    2111455
    2111456
```

So as you can see this is all in sequence, but now I want to achieve all trimmed zeros, like if this number got any zero, it should move to next sequence which is not having zero.

Like if it after moving ahead of 9, it shouldn't show 10 instead it should show 11,

1,2,3......8,9,11.....19,21....59,61.....99,111.... because 101, 102 again including zeros, so it should be having 111 directly.

Then 198,199...211.... as can't keep 201,202. Go gaps are undefined. Not a fixed interval. Tried a lots things. Getting closer but not correct at all.

**Output I want:**

```
            2111111
            2111112
            2111113
            2111114
            2111115
            2111116
            2111117
            2111118
            2111119
            2111121
            2111122
            2111123
            2111124
            2111125
            2111126
            2111127
            2111128
            2111129
            2111131
            2111132
            2111133
            2111134
            2111135
            2111136
            2111137
            2111138
            2111139
            2111141
            2111142
            2111143
            2111144
            2111145
            2111146
            2111147
            2111148
            2111149
            2111151
            2111152
            2111153
            2111154
            2111155
            2111156
            2111157
            2111158
            2111159
            2111161
            2111162
            2111163
            2111164
            2111165
            2111166
            2111167
            2111168
            2111169
            2111171
            2111172
            2111173
            2111174
            2111175
            2111176
            2111177
            2111178
            2111179
            2111181
            2111182
            2111183
            2111184
            2111185
            2111186
            2111187
            2111188
            2111189
            2111191
            2111192
            2111193
            2111194
            2111195
            2111196
            2111197
            2111198
            2111199
            2111211
            2111212
            2111213
            2111214
            2111215
            2111216
            2111217
            2111218
            2111219
            2111221
            2111222
            2111223
            2111224
            2111225
            2111226
            2111227
            2111228
            2111229
            2111231
            2111232
            2111233
            2111234
            2111235
            2111236
            2111237
            2111238
            2111239
            2111241
            2111242
            2111243
            2111244
            2111245
            2111246
            2111247
            2111248
            2111249
            2111251
            2111252
            2111253
            2111254
            2111255
            2111256
            2111257
            2111258
            2111259
            2111261
            2111262
            2111263
            2111264
            2111265
            2111266
            2111267
            2111268
            2111269
            2111271
            2111272
            2111273
            2111274
            2111275
            2111276
            2111277
            2111278
            2111279
            2111281
            2111282
            2111283
            2111284
            2111285
            2111286
            2111287
            2111288
            2111289
            2111291
            2111292
            2111293
            2111294
            2111295
            2111296
            2111297
            2111298
            2111299
            2111311
            2111312
            2111313
            2111314
            2111315
            2111316
            2111317
            2111318
            2111319
            2111321
            2111322
            2111323
            2111324
            2111325
            2111326
            2111327
            2111328
            2111329
            2111331
            2111332
            2111333
            2111334
            2111335
            2111336
            2111337
            2111338
            2111339
            2111341
            2111342
            2111343
            2111344
            2111345
            2111346
            2111347
            2111348
            2111349
            2111351
            2111352
            2111353
            2111354
            2111355
            2111356
            2111357
            2111358
            2111359
            2111361
            2111362
            2111363
            2111364
            2111365
            2111366
            2111367
            2111368
            2111369
            2111371
            2111372
            2111373
            2111374
            2111375
            2111376
            2111377
            2111378
            2111379
            2111381
            2111382
            2111383
            2111384
            2111385
            2111386
            2111387
            2111388
            2111389
            2111391
            2111392
            2111393
            2111394
            2111395
            2111396
            2111397
            2111398
            2111399
            2111411
            2111412
            2111413
            2111414
            2111415
            2111416
            2111417
            2111418
            2111419
            2111421
            2111422
            2111423
            2111424
            2111425
            2111426
            2111427
            2111428
            2111429
            2111431
            2111432
            2111433
            2111434
            2111435
            2111436
            2111437
            2111438
            2111439
            2111441
            2111442
            2111443
            2111444
            2111445
            2111446
            2111447
            2111448
            2111449
            2111451
            2111452
            2111453
            2111454
            2111455
            2111456
```

It shouldn't have any zeros, and once skipped any zero, it should move to the next sequence which is not having any zero too.

Comment: The output what you get and what you want is the same. Anyway, do we really need tons of lines from your output? Show just the relevant part.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Not same, so that you can see, my output is having 20, 30, 40, and what i want is skipping those, sorry if it bothered, but needed to make sure i explain it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is like "make something instead of me".
you can test if num have zero by condifion

```
if ((''+num).indexOf('0') != -1) {console.log(`this num have zero! ${num}`);}
```

Comment: then how do i skip this value ? like if i got to the point 199. then 200, 201,202....210 will be having zeros, i don't want those, i directly need 211..212...219..221....

Comment: use continue in for cycle
if (condition) {} 
else {continue;}

Comment: var result = parseInt(memberIdStart) + j;
    result = result + '';
    //console.log(memberIdStart+'--'+j);
    if(result.indexOf('0') === -1){
     console.log(result);
    }

Comment: @CrazyMax But then it would splice the number of outputs

Comment: A. Wolff yep, additional variable is needed and some rework of cycle https://jsfiddle.net/tb4za3m2/

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried your jsfiddle, it works, but only problem is, i need to run this loop for 13000 * 99 times, ( need to loop i for 13000, and j for 99 times.) , but if we skip those, then total amount of rows will not be 1287000 (13000 * 99)

Comment: @CrazyMax tried that, but same issue as i mentioned, if i continued, how do i will match the total rows to 13000 * 99. 

If i check how many times totally loop skipped and run those extras, will it help ?

Comment: @CrazyMax Working fine, really smart, now the next problem i am facing is, i need memberIDstart, that i captured using 

 if(j == 0) {
                memberiDinitial = curNum;
            }

But the same way i need memberid end, it means those rows should know the range of this 99 cards loop. 
 
i can iterate that afterwards, but before going into, 98  card loop, how to retrieve that ?